# Is walking with just the mouse possible in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, accessibility

I'd like to walk using only my mouse, for accessibility reasons, as I can do in some games like Diablo. I searched and didn't find any way.

Is there a game option to do this? Is there some other way to play that doesn't require my left hand for WASD walk keys?

Comment: Are you looking to just walk with your mouse, and use the keyboard for other things, or are you looking for mouse-only control?  I doubt the latter is possible, or if it is it is definitely not practical.  The former may be a possibility though.

Comment: i think he means click to move

Comment: As a note to the question author: you've asked a couple questions about click-to-move in various games.  Generally, games that use a first-person or over-the-shoulder view can not feasibly use click-to-move; terrain in those games are generally designed to be navigated as a three-dimensional space, whereas games like Diablo 3 have an overhead camera view and are navigated as a two-dimensional space.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, no. The gameplay mechanics aren't compatible with that sort of control scheme, and it's likely impossible to change that kind of fundamental aspect of the game's design and programming.

Even if you could somehow mod the interface to work like that, it wouldn't be playable. The game currently uses the mouse to control the vertical and horizontal angle of your view, which it uses for myriad purposes, chiefly to detect what your attacks are aimed at. If the mouse were co-opted to control movement by clicking where you want to go, you would be unable to attack anything while moving, leaving you easy pickings for enemies. To make such a control scheme work the game's control interface and enemy AI would have to be rewritten from the ground up.

Comment: Oh, *now* I get what you're saying.  I thought the OP was just asking about something that could simply be solved by assigning one of the mouse buttons to the walk command or something.  Clicking to specify destination though, is *definitely* not compatible with Skyrim's mechanics.

Comment: as a workaround, the op could bind the middle mouse to auto-walk (default is Q iirc)

Comment: @horatio I think you're missing the same point that I initially was - the OP doesn't want a "normal" walk command bound to a mouse control.  They want to be able to point-and-click to tell their avatar where to go, like in Diablo and other third-person RPGs.  (i.e.:  They want to click the ground next to the tree and have their avatar walk there.  They don't want to have to point the camera at that tree and hold or toggle a button to walk themselves there.)

Comment: "or a workaround"

Comment: @horatio Auto-walk isn't even related enough to click-to-walk to qualify as a workaround, even bound to a toggle key.

Comment: @horatio Ah, I see what you're getting at, now that I've read the OP's other question. Being an accessibility issue, binding a mouse button to auto-walk *would* be a second-best solution, even if its not anything like click-to-walk. The problem is that the OP asked for something specific (click-to-walk "like Diablo"), but their real problem is needing to avoid left-hand input. Askers, please always tell us the problem, not just if your random best-guess solution works! ;)

Comment: "Askers, please always tell us the problem, not just if your random best-guess solution works!"  YES, please.  This should be in the FAQ on every site (I have to ask this so much on SU it's not even funny)